# Shell scripts in Git Bash on Windows 7

Tags: windows, bash, git, shell

I'm generally having success running shell scripts in Git Bash, but this one runs but does nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd c:/inetpub/wwwroot/electronWork
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

How are you running the script?  If you invoke it like `./script.sh` it will create a sub-shell, and change to that directory inside your sub-shell, then exit.  If you run it using `source ./script.sh` it will run the script inside the current shell and change directory there (which I assume is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Is that the whole script? If so, then it's probably working fine, changing to the directory, then exiting back to your parent which *didn't* do the cd.

Have it do something, like pwd and/or ls -l so that you can see it worked, though when it's done it still won't have changed the directory of the caller.

To do that you need to source it as [Alex Stiff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8096842/alex-stiff) said.

```
. whateverYourScriptIsNamed
```

That would actually make the commands in the file be executed in your context instead of as a subshell.

I think what you may want instead, though, is an alias:

```
alias eWork='cd /c/inetpub/wwwroot/electronWork'
```

then you type `eWork` and it changes your dir.

If you need anything more elaborate that requires arguments, write a function, but you can look that up. ;)